# Factory Girl failing presence validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have the following task model:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }
  validates :complete, presence: true
end
```

and following FactoryGirl object creation code:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :incomplete_task, class: :Task do
    body { Faker::Pokemon.name + Faker::Pokemon.name }
    complete false

    factory :complete_task do
      complete true
    end
  end
end
```

In my Tasks controller tests, I have:

```
  describe '#update' do
    it 'toggles completion' do
      incomplete_task = create :incomplete_task
      toggle_completion(incomplete_task)
      expect(incomplete_task.complete).to be_true
    end
  end
```

However, this fails because the field 'complete' is missing from the task object created by FG:

```
Failures:
  1) TasksController#update toggles completion
     Failure/Error: incomplete_task = create :incomplete_task

     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Complete can't be blank
```

What is going on here? I'm properly setting the complete attribute, and body is checking out fine.  Here is the task schema as well:

```
# Table name: tasks
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  body       :text
#  complete   :boolean
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ruby, `false` is considered a blank (not present) value (along with `nil`, empty string/array and other blank values). Therefore, the presence validator rightfully rejects that record.

The [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_presence_of) has the following comment:

> If you want to validate the presence of a boolean field (where the real values are `true` and `false`), you will want to use `validates_inclusion_of :field_name, in: [true, false]`.
>
> This is due to the way `Object#blank?` handles boolean values: `false.blank? # => true`.